# Некорректно работает js на iphone

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, safari

Помогите решить проблему работы js на iphone - бьюсь третий день, никак не пойму как решить.
Сайт: https://ugli33.ru при переходе в любой пункт меню из меню расположенного под кнопкой "Меню" снизу это самое меню всегда остается развернутым. Почему-то не срабатывает добавление класса mini, которое должно вот этим кодом работать:

```
if($(window).width() < 1199) {
  $('.sidebar').addClass('mini');
  $('.main').addClass('max');;
}
```

Comment: Так у вас имя для стилей добавляется при в `sidebar` и `main` при `if($(window).width() < 1199)` скорее всего проблема в стиле, для `iphone'а` иногда работает другие типа `-webkit-` и прочее

Comment: @newProgrammer, так я вроде пытаюсь добавить на сам стиль а класс.

Comment: https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ссылочка полезная, а по моему вопросу чем-то поможете?

Comment: @Batyabest так а без отладчика что тут скажешь

Comment: @Batyabest можно еще по старинке, весь отладочный вывод в div на экране напечатать

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я пока не имею возможности установить себе все то что по ссылке, поэтому обратился сюда за помощью - тем кто может посмотреть отладку и помочь с вопросом)